# sencha app build production error?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am building an app with Sencha Command, I have followed all the steps and everything has worked fine until I enter the command `sencha app build production`. I am getting the following errors

```
[ERROR] CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified.


[ERROR] Failed loading your application from: 'http://localhost/am/index.html'. Try setting the absolute URL to your application for the 'url' item inside 'app.json'
```

I am using the most up to date sencha touch sdk tools and sencha touch 2 sdk.

I do not know why these errors exist and I have tried every solution I could think of to fix them.

I have browsed through most of the sencha forums and other sites looking for an answer but to no avail.

Does anyone know why I would be getting these errors and or a solution to fix the errors?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using? Have you tried building a freshly created application?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using Windows 7. I did try building a freshly created application and then running the sencha app build production command but I still got the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do what the error recommend: "Try setting the absolute URL to your application for the 'url' item inside 'app.json'" ?